# What is the location of macOS logon file?

Tags: macos, monterey, file, zsh, logs

Cant find location of OSX logon data file. Where I will be able to extract following info:

- DateStamps of console and tty creation.
- Username that run those sessions.
- How long sessions have been active.

To be more precisely, I need output similar to `last` command shell or `w` command shell.

What I have tried:

I used `man last` and `man w` to lookup filenames from where they extract such data, but the files either are not exists or output is not close to the output from commands above on **MacOS Monterey**.

Comment: What did you learn when you looked at the sources for `last` and `w` ?

Comment: @MarcWilson, `/var/log/wtmp`, `/var/log/btmp` from `last` and `/var/run/utmp`  from `w`. Tried to lookup analogs to them for macOS, but the only file that gives some kind of similar output was `/var/run/utmpx`

Comment: Funny, the source for Apple's `last` doesn't reference anything in `/var/log`.  https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/adv_cmds/blob/60bc9ebf1df7e0a3d8500ecd7e4dd1e008765af5/last/last.c